# How can I insert 200k objects using node.js ,mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have 200 000 users. I want to insert through `node.js`. How can I modify my controller function?

```
exports.create = function(req, res, next) {
    var newUser = new User(req.body);
    newUser.provider = 'local';
    newUser.role = 'user';
    newUser.save(function(err, user) {
        if (err) 
            return validationError(res, err);
        var token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id }, config.secrets.session, { expiresInMinutes: 60*5 });
        res.json({ token: token });
    });
};
```

I tried but I am getting error like this

```
  Error: request entity too large
    at readStream (Test\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:196:17)
    at getRawBody (Test\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:106:12)
    at read (Test\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:76:3)
    at jsonParser (Test\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:127:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (Test\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
    at trim_prefix (Test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:270:13)
    at Test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:237:9
    at Function.proto.process_params (Test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:12)
    at Test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:228:12
    at Function.match_layer (Test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:295:3)
    at next (Test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:189:10)
    at urlencodedParser (Test\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:100:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (Test\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
    at trim_prefix (Test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:270:13)
    at Test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:237:9
    at Function.proto.process_params (Test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:12)
```

Comment: what does the L in `2L` signify?

Comment: 2 lakhs @JaromandaX

Comment: You can use mongodb bulk upload option

Comment: can you pls help me out @naveendahiya

Comment: so, `200,000`  (or is that `2,00,000`?)

Comment: 2,06,459  have @JaromandaX

Comment: well, that's not nearly 2 lakhs - that's over 2 lakhs :p (I'll remove the gibberish shortly, but I like it when I learn something unexpected)

Comment: Create a file in json format of all the objects using any language, then by using bulk insert of mongodb you can insert this data in few minutes. I inserted 50milion objects using the same process. It will help you and a simple process.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/Bulk.insert/

Comment: looks like the problem could be a limit to the size of data coming from a HTTP request - so, bulk insert on mongo wont help if you can't even access the data in the request

Comment: if you are receiving all data in single request then surely you have to increase size of http receiver, so that you can read input and after that you can use bulk insert.

Comment: how can i do that help me out @naveendahiya